# Returning model to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project that looks like this:
[image]

When I enter all the fields, and I choose the dates I want to report a time for. 
If there is an error such as if the hours are not correct I want to return the same view so the user doesn't need to enter everything again.

It kinda works, "Beskrivning" and "Timmar:" Gets filled back with the values that were sent it, but the dates I've chosen are not.

This is my model:

```
    public class NewTimeReportModel
{
    public TimeReportTimes Times;
    public List<Project> Projects;
    public Guid? ReportId;
    public DateTime Date;
    public bool NoTimeToReport;
    public Dictionary<Guid, double?> ProjectDictionary
    {
        get { return Projects.ToDictionary(x => x.ProjectId, x => x.Hours); }
    }
    public NewTimeReportModel()
    {
        Projects = new List<Project>();
    }
    public NewTimeReportModel(Report report)
    {
        ReportId = report.TimeReportID;
        Projects = new List<Project>();
        foreach (var projectData in report.TimeReportProjects)
        {
            Projects.Add(new Project
            {
                Description = projectData.Description,
                Hours = projectData.Hours,
                ProjectId = projectData.FK_ProjectID
            });
        }

        Times = new TimeReportTimes(report.TimeReportDatas.Single());
        NoTimeToReport = report.NoTimeToReport;
        Date = report.Date;
    }
    public class Project
    {
        public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double? Hours { get; set; }
        public bool SetHours(string hours)
        {
            double value;
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hours))
                {
                    value = -1;
                }
                else if (hours.Contains(":"))
                {
                    string[] vals = hours.Split(':');
                    value = double.Parse(vals[0]) + new TimeSpan(0, int.Parse(vals[1]), 0).TotalHours;
                }
                else if (hours.Contains(","))
                {
                    value = double.Parse(hours);
                }
                else if (!double.TryParse(hours, out value))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

            Hours = value;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This is my controller where I return the view.

```
    public ActionResult TimeReport(FormCollection form, Guid? id, bool? noTimeToReport)
    {
        ShowProjects(true);

        NewTimeReportModel projectData = new NewTimeReportModel();

        //Deletes Timereport
        if (form != null && form.AllKeys.Contains("delete"))
        {
            new DatabaseLayer().DeleteTimeReport(Guid.Parse(form["ReportId"]));
            LoadDefaultSettings(projectData);
            ViewData.Model = projectData;
            ViewData["deleted"] = true;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        //Update Timereport
        if (id.HasValue && (form == null || form.AllKeys.Length == 0))
        {
            using (DatabaseLayer db = new DatabaseLayer())
            {
                var timeReport = db.GetTimeReport(id.Value);
                projectData = new NewTimeReportModel(timeReport);
            }
        }
        //Loads default settings
        else if (form == null || form.AllKeys.Length == 0)
        {
            LoadDefaultSettings(projectData);
        }
        else
        {
            //Get's all the dates from the view and formates them to look like yy-mm-dd so we can parse it to a datetime.
            List<string> dates = FormateDate(form["date"]);
            //Loops over all the dates and saves the dates to the database.
            projectData = ReportDates(form, projectData, dates, noTimeToReport);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //If we get this far everything is ok and we save the timereport to the database
                projectData.SaveToDatabase(Constants.CurrentUser(User.Identity.Name));
                ViewData["posted"] = true;
                projectData = new NewTimeReportModel();
            }
            else if (projectData.Projects.Count == 1)
            {
                ListAllMssingDays();
                ViewData.Model = projectData;
                return View(projectData);
            }

            //Loads default settings if all dates been reported.
            LoadDefaultSettings(projectData);
        }
        //Get's and lists all the missing days
        ListAllMssingDays();
        ViewData.Model = projectData;
        return View();
    }
```

This is how I choose my dates on my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
//Select seperate date
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="isoDate"]').change(function() {
        $("#date").val("");
        $('input[name="isoDate"]').each(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                $("#date").val($("#date").val() + " " + $(this).val());
            }
        });
    });
});

//Select all dates inside the month
$(function () {
    $(".selectAll").on("click", function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            if($(this).closest('.panel-default').length > 0)
                $(this).closest('.panel-default').find("input[name='isoDate']").prop('checked', this.checked);
            else
                $("input[name='isoDate']").prop('checked', this.checked);
            $('input[name="isoDate"]').trigger('change');
        } else {
            if($(this).closest('.panel-default').length > 0)
                $(this).closest('.panel-default').find("input[name='isoDate']").prop('checked', false);
            else
                $("input[name='isoDate']").prop('checked', false);
            $('input[name="isoDate"]').trigger('change');
        }
    });
});
```

And this is my view:

```
<div class="portlet-body form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-5">Ingen tid att rapportera</label>
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.NoTimeToReport, new { @id = "check" })
                                    </div>
                                    @if (Model.ReportId.HasValue)
                                    {
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Redigera datum:</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                                @Html.TextBox("date", Model.Date.ToShortDateString(), new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "true" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Start tid:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            @Html.TextBox("startTime", Model.Times.StartTime, new { @class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Slut tid:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            @Html.TextBox("endTime", Model.Times.EndTime, new { @class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Rast Längd:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            @Html.TextBox("breakTime", Model.Times.BreakTime, new { @class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Tid jobbad:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            @Html.TextBox("workedHours", Model.Times.WorkedHours, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Show the model and the full controller POST method code. You not correctly binding to your model and no doubt have other errors as well

Comment: @StephenMuecke Updated.

Comment: Oh dear, Where did your ever get the idea this is how to write code for MVC. You have still not shown your models

Comment: @StephenMuecke Added my model..

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but almost everything here is awful. No time now but I will have a look a later.

Comment: @StephenMuecke criticism is good. How else am I going to improve?

Comment: I think one of the things that would make your life easier is to use your model as the parameter in the POST.

Comment: @foobar, Your fundamental problem is that your not binding to properties of your model and your not posting back your model (you should never use `FormCollection`. But lets look at your first `if` block in the POST method. `if (form != null)`. Unless you have included a control with `name="form"` in your view, the value of `form` can never be `null`. Then your call `LoadDefaultSettings` and set 2 `ViewData` properties but then redirect, meaning the previous 3 lines are completely pointless (its all lost the moment you redirect).

Comment: Later you test `if (ModelState.IsValid)` - again pointless since you don't have a model and nothing is ever added to `ModelState` so its always valid. Then you do thing like `ViewData.Model = projectData; return View(projectData);` - your just adding the same model to the `ViewDataDictionary` twice. Unfortunately I don't understand the language so unsure what you doing here

Comment: @StephenMuecke It's a basic Time Reporting System, I pass in dates I want to report time for, the amount of hours I did work, and the projeckt(s) I did work on.

Answer (score 0):

When you checking that user entry is not valid then return View with implemented model so that it will bind to view again.`return View(projectData);`

Comment: That's what I am doing

Comment: Remove ToShortDateString() from ur startTime Field

Comment: That field is only being used if you pass in a ReportId to the constructor. Aka when you want to edit / remove a time report. I have Hiddenfields for the dates I pass into the middle.

Comment: My be your problem in JQuery code. make sure and test in Mozila firefox with firbug.